# Segmentation fault after SYSTEM call execution

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Please tell me what I am doing is right or wrong. And if it is right then why I am getting segmentation fault?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* EncodeToBase64(char*);

int main()
{
    char str[24] = {0};
    char *output = NULL;
    output = malloc(56*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
    output = EncodeToBase64(str);
    printf("Back %s",*output);
    return 0;
}

char* EncodeToBase64(char *str)
{
    char buff[24];
    char *output = NULL;
    output = malloc(56*sizeof(char));
    memset(buff,'0',sizeof(buff));
    printf("EncodeToBase64 Function\n");
    sprintf(buff,"echo %s | openssl enc -base64",str);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    output = system(buff);
    printf("Back %s",*output);

    return output;
}
```

After correcting my code I got one more issue,Everytime I am getting these three characters appended in my string `ô/+`... How to get exact string?

Comment: For every `malloc()` there should be a `free()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system()` returns an `int`, which is the *exit status* of the process, not the standard output.
So assigning the return value of `system()` to a `char *` and printing that
does not make any sense.

You can use `popen()` to start a process and read its output.

**Example** (using fixed sized buffers and no error checking for brevity):

```
char * EncodeToBase64(char *str)
{
    char buff[1024], output[1024];

    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "echo %s | openssl enc -base64", str);
    FILE *fp = popen(buff, "r");
    size_t amount = fread(output, 1, sizeof(output) - 1, fp);
    output[amount] = 0; // zero terminate string
    fclose(fp);

    return strdup(output);
}
```

Usage:

```
char *b64 = EncodeToBase64("Hello world");
printf("%s", b64);
free(b64);
// Output: SGVsbG8gd29ybGQK
```

Comment: Can I use `system` as an argument to `popen`?? `popen(system,"r");`?

Comment: @Krishna: The first argument of popen() is the same as the system() argument, so `FILE *fp = popen(buff, "r")` in your case.

Comment: but still i am not getting this output in my main function.

Comment: @Krishna This answer is correct, but so is sr01853's answer. There are so many issues with your code that none of the answers completely cover them.  You need to do more research as you are turning into a help vampire.

Comment: @trojanfoe... I got my mistakes... Thanks for your help... One more problem, Everytime I am getting these three characters appended in my string `ô/+`... How to get exact string?

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("Back %s",output);
```

when printing a string, `output` is the argument

Its a good practise to `free` the memory that was `malloc`'ed

I dont think the `malloc` in `main()` is necessary.

Comment: @Krishna: Did you correct **both** occurrencies of `printf()`ing `*output`?